# Apache Spark - Adding two columns

Tags: java, apache-spark

Is there a way to add two columns so that the first one is a date and the second one contains the number of days that need to be added? I'm trying

```
date_add(res.col("date"), res.col("days"));
```

But this doesn't work, since `date_add()` requires a `Column` and an `int`, while I have two columns.

Thank you!

Comment: I'd write a UDF to do this.

Comment: How would that look like? Haven't been able to find proper info about it. Thank you!

Comment: Apparently this is not possible, the arguments of a UDF are of the type scala.reflect.api.TypeTags.TypeTag which includes Int, Double, Boolean,...  (see http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0-M4/scala-reflect/scala/reflect/api/TypeTags$TypeTag$.html) but not Date nor Timestamp. Ie. you can't build a UDF with Date columns as arguments.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you, still! The `expr` solution below works fine, though. :)

Comment: I was wrong: you CAN use Date's in UDFs. See the extra answer I added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a limitation of `DataFrame` DSL not engine itself. It is not optimal but you can replace function call with `expr`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{expr, col}

val df = Seq(("2012-04-05", 6))
  .toDF("date", "days")
  .withColumn("date", col("date").cast("date"))

df.select(expr("date_add(date, days)"))
```

Comment: It takes a chunk of raw SQL to be parsed.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to combine regular select with expr? Like `df.select("column1", expr("date_add(date, days)"))` ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: How? `df.select("column1", expr("date_add(date, days)"))` didn't work for me. Spark said it cannot be resolved.

Comment: Wrong signature. `expr` needs column so other objects have to be columns as well.

Comment: I don't get your answer. `column1` is a column. Could you show me the correct way to do it with code? Thank you!

Comment: `"column1"` is a string.   `col("column1")` for example is a `Column`. You're coding in Java so mind the types.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution using a **UDF**: see following function definition of  `udfDateAdd()`

The sql function date_add() cannot be used here: the java.sql.Date is first converted to a LocalDate (java8), after which days are added, and then converted back again to a java.sql.Date :

```
import java.sql.Date
import java.time.LocalDate;

// sample data
val df = Seq(("2015-02-21", 8), ("2016-02-21", 8)).toDF("date", "days").
   withColumn("date", col("date").cast("date"))

val udfDateAdd=udf[Date,Date,Int]{ (dt,inc) => 
    java.sql.Date.valueOf( dt.toLocalDate().plusDays(inc) ) }
```

Result:

```
df.withColumn("newdate", udfDateAdd($"date",$"days")).show()

+----------+----+----------+
|      date|days|   newdate|
+----------+----+----------+
|2015-02-21|   8|2015-03-01|
|2016-02-21|   8|2016-02-29|
+----------+----+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you! Is `val df` valid JAVA under Spark? I thought this was Scala-specific, but I don't know, I'm asking out of curiosity. :)

Comment: I've given you the scala solution!